# How to set the dimensions of a button equal to a variable in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make a program where I can change the width of a button with a variable, but it doesn't update. I alredy know how to do the same with it's text, but I can't with it's dimensions. Also i can't leave the dimensions to default, because i have multiple buttons, all of them need to have the same dimensions, but diferent text.

The first thing I tried is to change the width command for a widthvariable, as this works with text to textvariable, but it just doesn't exist.
Also I tried setting width=var but it doesn't.

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

myFrame=Frame()

myFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

idioma=StringVar(myFrame)
idioma.set("Català")
idiomes_possibles=["Català", "Español", "English", "Deutsch"]
idiomes_possibles=OptionMenu(myFrame, idioma, *idiomes_possibles)
idiomes_possibles.config(width=10)
idiomes_possibles.grid(row=1, column=0)

vari=IntVar()
vari.set(15)
varia=vari.get()
def change_dropdown(*args):
    idioma_elegit=idioma.get()
    if(idioma_elegit=="Català"):
        vari.set(15)
        varia=vari.get()
    elif(idioma_elegit=="Español"):
        vari.set(17)
        varia=vari.get()
botó_recta=Button(myFrame, width=varia)
botó_recta.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

I expect that changing the idioma variable changes the varia variable and also the button resizes, does all except resizing the button.
Thanks.

Comment: You set the width of the button *once*, using a value that came from the variable `varia`.  Further changes to that variable have absolutely no effect on the button.  You'd have to set the width again, which can be written either as `botó_recta['width'] = varia` or `botó_recta.config(width=varia)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to actually change the width of the button in your function `change_dropdown`. But you also haven't assigned the function as the callback function to your `OptionMenu`, so nothing actually happens after you change the selection. Something like this should work:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
myFrame=Frame()
myFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

idioma=StringVar(myFrame)
idioma.set("Català")
idiomes_possibles=["Català", "Español", "English", "Deutsch"]
idiomes_possibles=OptionMenu(myFrame, idioma, *idiomes_possibles, command=change_dropdown)
idiomes_possibles.config(width=10)
idiomes_possibles.grid(row=1, column=0)

vari=IntVar()
vari.set(15)
varia=vari.get()
botó_recta=Button(myFrame, width=varia)
def change_dropdown(*args):
    idioma_elegit=idioma.get()
    if(idioma_elegit=="Català"):
        vari.set(15)
        varia=vari.get()
    elif(idioma_elegit=="Español"):
        vari.set(30)
        varia=vari.get()    
    botó_recta['width'] = varia


botó_recta.grid(row=0, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```